# Adding a product to a product group with MEME via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-error-reporting

I'm trying to automate the creation of the product mapping through the PowerShell module that comes with Microsoft Ecosystem Metadata Exchange product mapping tool. I've managed to get the product created and files mapped successfully, the output file also import's fine into the tool itself. The problem I'm having is adding the Product to the Product Group through the PowerShell module. I keep getting the error: `Must add the product to the store before adding product groups` with the following script:

```
$path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application"
$outputFilePath = "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\WER\NewProduct.emx"

# Create new product
$product = New-Product -Name "Application" -Version "2.0.0.180" -Lifecycle PreRelease
Add-Product -Product $product

# Scan directory for files
#$files = New-ProductFile $path

# Associate files with product
Add-ProductFile $product -ProductFile $files

# Add product to group
$productGroup = New-ProductGroup -Name "Application" -Version "2"
Add-ProductGroup -ProductGroup $productGroup -Product $product

Export-MetaData $outputFilePath
```

As you can see, I try to add the group after I have created the product but it doesn't work. Ideally there'd be some way to set a groups variable by getting the ProductGroups from an exported metadata file but this PowerShell module is extremely limited with only two resources available on the subject. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm having is adding the Product to the Product Group through the PowerShell module.

As the error message says you have to add the product group to the store first.
After you create the product group just add the following line:

```
Add-ProductGroup -ProductGroup $productGroup
```

> Ideally there'd be some way to set a groups variable by getting the ProductGroups from an exported metadata file

For this problem the following commands should be helpful:

- Import-Metadata
- Set-Metadata
- Merge-Metadata
- Clear-Metadata
- Get-Product
- Get-ProductGroup

E.g. if you know that the Product Group 'GroupX' you want to add a new product to is stored in file 'metadata.emx' you could do the following:

```
$md = Import-Metadata -Path 'metadata.emx'
Merge-Metadata -Metadata $md #use Set-Metadata if you want to replace the current metadata
$productGroup = Get-ProductGroup -Name 'GroupX'
```